# How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin when using @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, http, header, response

I am using @RestController to provide a REST service. But I need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header. How would I do this?

My RestController:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class restController  {

   @RequestMapping("/some")
   public Response some(@RequestParam(value="body")  String user) {
      return new Response(user);
   }
}
```

My Response:

```
public class Response {

  long id;
  String user;

  public Response(String user) {
       this.id = 7;
       this.user = user;
  }
}
```

@RestController works very well but how can I modify it or the response to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: Please check out https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
   @RequestMapping("/some")
   public Response some(@RequestParam(value="body")  String user) {
      return new Response(user);
   }
```

or this

```
@RequestMapping("/some")
public Response some(@RequestParam(value="body")  String user,HttpServletResponse 
response) {
   response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   return new Response(user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Is there a way to see this change in the browser? For example in the web developer console of firefox?

Comment: You can see response header like CORS in any browsers dev tool  network section..

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions above but am not seeing anything like a CORS response in the network section of Firefox

Comment: My response header has only the following: HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 12:08:18 GMT

Comment: okay now I see it: HTTP/1.1 200 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 13:10:57 GMT

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000") at the top of my class or before method in REST controller works. Thanks a lot!
Example:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;


    @PostMapping("/api/user/login")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    ResponseEntity<Object> customerLogin(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            UserDto entity = userService.login(userDto);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(entity);

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```